# PuTTY unable to save key files

Tags: putty

I downloaded PuTTYGen as a standalone binary and used it to generate public/private key pairs. When clicking 'save public/private' key and entering the file names and enter, it pops up 'Unable to save key file'. I researched a bit on the net but simply can't find an answer as to how can I solve this problem. It doesn't matter if I password protect the keys generated, it doesn't work.

Why this happens and how to solve this? TIA.

p.s. I'm already in admin rights and the folder to where I'm storing the keys I've full read/write access.

p.s. I cannot install putty (where every binaries are there), with error "Installation directory must be on a local drive". That's why I install the standalone binary.

Comment: Where are you saving the files to? Do you have permissions to save those files there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @music2myear, I'm already admininstrator and that's the folder where I have been storing my work.

Comment: That information needs to be in the question. The fact you cannot install things tells me there is more you haven't told us about your situation. If you were admin on your computer you'd be able to install the software.

Comment: @music2myear, thank you for advising me my edit. I add it back to my question the info you suggested. But the problem remains: I'm an admin with full rights but still this issue exists.

Comment: Some screenshots showing what exactly are you doing would be helpful. From the errors you are getting, it looks like, that there's no physical drive on your system. Is it?

Comment: @Hing Please add the output of `icacls <path\to\folder>` of the folder you're trying to save the keys to

Comment: @MartinPrikryl true. Thanks for the suggestion! you reminded me that folder is C:/ but belongs to OneDrive. When I save on other 'phyiscal disks' it succeeds. Why is that?

Comment: @JW0914 despite the problem now solved. I would revert to you the following outputs: <my folder path> NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
                                   BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
                                   DESKTOP-18EBFEF\mhwon:(OI)(CI)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

Comment: Your entire C drive is being backed up to OneDrive? Normally it is just the Documents and a couple other folders that are saved to OneDrive.

Comment: @music2myear, sorry for the wordings. It's just the document to OneDrive, where the folder-to-save occurs to be under Documents

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. I am admin and I can install and download things to my computer but for some reason puttygen cannot save files on my machine.  While I look for a sustainable solution I have been using this workaround.
Open puttygen as admin then save it in the C drive.

Save in C drive:
[image: Save in C drive.]